# Setting the stroke color of the title text in UINavigationBar's appearance

Tags: ios

Is there some problem setting a nav bar's title text stroke color? If have the following code

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:19],
                                                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                                       NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:215/255.0f green:75/255.0f blue:40/255.0f alpha:1],
                                                       NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:@-3.0
                                                       }]; UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

The font name and color appear fine, but the stroke color and width are not reflected in the UI. Anyone figure this out?